# Move image using thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-view

I'm making an example that an image can moving from left to right using thread. If user touch that image, thread pause for 3 second then continue moving.
I've known about TranslateAnimation animation but on my example can't use this.
I don't have much experience with thread. Which type of thread that I should use for this case. It's awsome if has an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use any Thread at all, what you should use instead is a Handler and a Message/Runnable